# Adding new databases to existing maintenance backup plan

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to automate our backup plans to add newly created backups automatically on SQL server 2008. Is there a way to do this?
Since it wont let me comment on this to clarify. I am trying to add new databases that we have created to an existing Management Maintenance Plan on SQL Server 2008. I am trying to make it a script that we can run that will automatically add the database when created. Is this possible?

Comment: Your question alludes to the fact that you are using SQL Server maintenance plans? If you are and want to modify see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326729(v=sql.105).aspx -if you are using them you should instead move to Scripted agent jobs (such as Ola's scripts as mentioned).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the well used [ola hallengren.](https://ola.hallengren.com/)scripts.

Make use of the [SQL Server Backup](http://SQL%20Server%20Backup) scripts available on the above.

Eg:

> Back up all user databases, using checksums and compression; verify
>   the backup; and delete old backup files

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@Directory = 'C:\Backup',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Verify = 'Y',
@Compress = 'Y',
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = 24
```

Then run the above script on SQL server agent job as per the backup plan strategy to execute this.

Also, just to mention you need to first create the scripts [CommandExecute.sql and DatabaseBackup.sql](https://ola.hallengren.com/downloads.html) in order to use the backup plan.